# How do I sort a list and use its changed indexes to sort another list in java?

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting

I have 3 lists:

```
ArrayList<Integer> at = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2, 0, 2, 3, 4));
ArrayList<Integer> bt = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2, 1, 3, 5, 4)); 
ArrayList<String> prc = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "p5"));
```

If I sort `at`, I'll get `[0, 2, 2, 3, 4`].
I want both `bt` and `prc` to follow this pattern. i.e: `bt =[1, 2, 3, 5, 4]` and
`prc=["p2", "p1", "p3", "p4", "p5"]`. Since at `at` index 1 got swapped with index 2 upon sort, I want the same thing to happen with the other 2 arrays as well.

I tried implementing this in Python. It was easy because, if the values are in a data frame, sorting one column will automatically give the required result. I couldn't do the same in Java.

Answer (score 2):

#### Method 1 *(extract indexes first and construct new list)*

*If you can change the data format and use a custom object, I recommend to use method 2.*

You can first extract the indexes of the original elements in `at` into an array `sortedIndices`. If the list is already sorted, the value would be `[1, 2, 3, ..., n-1]`. If the first two elements need to be swapped, the value would be `[1, 0, 2, 3, ..., n-1]`. Afterwards, you can construct and populate the two sorted lists (`btSorted`/`prcSorted`) by adding the elements according to the position stored `sortedIndices[i]`.

```
ArrayList<Integer> at = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2, 0, 2, 3, 4));
ArrayList<Integer> bt = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2, 1, 3, 5, 4));
ArrayList<String> prc = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "p5"));

// get indexes of a sorted 'at' list
int[] sortedIndices = IntStream.range(0, at.size())
        .boxed().sorted(Comparator.comparing(at::get))
        .mapToInt(x -> x).toArray();

// sort 'bt' according to 'at'
ArrayList<Integer> btSorted = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < sortedIndices.length; i++) {
    btSorted.add(bt.get(sortedIndices[i]));
}

// sort 'prc' according to 'at'
ArrayList<String> prcSorted = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < sortedIndices.length; i++) {
    prcSorted.add(prc.get(sortedIndices[i]));
}

// sort 'at' directly (just for inspection)
ArrayList<Integer> atSorted = new ArrayList<>(at);
Collections.sort(atSorted);

System.out.println("idx: " + Arrays.toString(sortedIndices));
System.out.println("at:  " + at + " => " + atSorted);
System.out.println("bt:  " + bt + " => " + btSorted);
System.out.println("prc: " + prc + " => " + prcSorted);
```

*Output:*

```
idx: [1, 0, 2, 3, 4]
at:  [2, 0, 2, 3, 4] => [0, 2, 2, 3, 4]
bt:  [2, 1, 3, 5, 4] => [1, 2, 3, 5, 4]
prc: [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5] => [p2, p1, p3, p4, p5]
```

---

#### Method 2  *(custom class and `Comparator`)*

**Much more readable** would be to store the data in a **custom class** (e.g. `DataEntry`). Then, you can easily sort the array of objects (e.g. `data`) without resorting to hard to read code:

```
ArrayList<DataEntry> data = new ArrayList<>();
data.add(new DataEntry(2, 2, "p1"));
data.add(new DataEntry(0, 1, "p2"));
data.add(new DataEntry(2, 3, "p3"));
data.add(new DataEntry(3, 5, "p4"));
data.add(new DataEntry(4, 4, "p5"));

// sort data by 'at'
data.sort(Comparator.comparing(d -> d.at));

// print result
data.forEach(d -> System.out.println(d.at + ", " + d.bt + ", " + d.prc));
```

*Output:*

```
0, 1, p2
2, 2, p1
2, 3, p3
3, 5, p4
4, 4, p5
```

*`DataEntry` class for reference:*

```
static class DataEntry {
    int at;
    int bt;
    String prc;

    public DataEntry(int at, int bt, String prc) {
        this.at = at;
        this.bt = bt;
        this.prc = prc;
    }
}
```

---

#### Method 3 *(with `indexOf` and `Comparator`)*

*This is only stable when there are no duplicates in the lists to be sorted (`bt`/`prc`) since `indexOf` always returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in a list (or -1).*

Sorting the lists could be done with a custom `Comparator` and `indexOf`. We can refer to the values in `at` at the respective position of the current element being compared (`d`) in the other lists (`bt`/`prc`) in order to sort them:

```
ArrayList<Integer> at = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2, 0, 2, 3, 4));
ArrayList<Integer> bt = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2, 1, 3, 5, 4));
ArrayList<String> prc = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "p5"));

// sort 'bt' according to 'at'
ArrayList<Integer> btSorted = new ArrayList<>(bt);
btSorted.sort(Comparator.comparing(d -> at.get(bt.indexOf(d))));

// sort prc according to 'at'
ArrayList<String> prcSorted = new ArrayList<>(prc);
prcSorted.sort(Comparator.comparing(d -> at.get(prc.indexOf(d))));

// sort 'at' (just for inspection)
ArrayList<Integer> atSorted = new ArrayList<>(at);
Collections.sort(atSorted);

// print result
System.out.println(at + " => " + atSorted);
System.out.println(bt + " => " + btSorted);
System.out.println(prc + " => " + prcSorted);
```

*Output:*

```
at:  [2, 0, 2, 3, 4] => [0, 2, 2, 3, 4]
bt:  [2, 1, 3, 5, 4] => [1, 2, 3, 5, 4]
prc: [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5] => [p2, p1, p3, p4, p5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options.
The first is kind of obvious and I am curious as why it might not be an option for you.

Option 1)

Create a class containing values for at, bt, prc implementing Comparable where compareTo(Foo other) returns at-other.at;

Option 2)

Create a new array containing indexes like:

```java
    ArrayList<Integer> indexes = List.of(0,1,2,3,4);
    indexes.sort(new Comparator(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
       return at[o1.intValue()]-at[o2.intValue()];
    })
```

The resulting list will be something like {1,0,2,3,4} then:

```java
    ArrayList<Integer> newAt = new ArrayList<>()
    ArrayList<Integer> newBt = new ArrayList<>()
    ArrayList<String> newPrc = new ArrayList<>()

    for(Integer i : indexes) {
      newAt.add(at.get(i));
      newBt.add(bt.get(i));
      newPrc.add(prc.get(i));
    }
```

Comment: Ohh well great minds think alike, ignore my post first post is exactly the same but written better.